# SwiftUI - Opening sheet without button click

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos

I am able to sheet over current view when I click on a button.

However I have scenarios where I query for data and as soon as data is received, instead of showing a message in the view, I wish to open a sheet programmatically without any user interaction and show a short message on the sheet to let the user know that their action was successful. My code for opening the sheet programmatically isn't working.

***Code for opening sheet via button click(this code works):***

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomView: View {
    @State var showingModal: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomButton(imageName: imageName, action: { self.showingModal.toggle() })
            .sheet ( isPresented: $showingModal,
                content: {
                    let messageViewDetails = getMessageViewDetails()

                    ShowMessageAlert(rawValue: messageViewDetails.actionType.rawValue)?.showGeneralMessageView(messageText: messageViewDetails.messageText, showingModal: $showingModal)
                }
            )
        }
    }

    // func for getMessageViewDetails
}
```

***Below 2 structs is the code for opening sheet programmatically:***

```
import SwiftUI

struct OtherCustomView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: CustomViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Hello World").font(.callout).foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }.padding(.bottom, 10).padding(.top, 10)

            // Removed other states to keep the code short and easy to understand
            switch viewModel.state {
            case .idle:
                Color.clear.onAppear(perform: { viewModel.getData() })
            case .loading:
                ProgressView()
            case .response(let isSuccess, let result):
                ShowResponseView(isSuccess: isSuccess, result: result)
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("Back")
        .onDisappear() {
            viewModel.state = .idle
        }
    }
}
```

**// Code for ShowResponseView which will be reused for other states as well in OtherCustomView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ShowResponseView: View {
    @State var showingModal: Bool = false
    var isSuccess: Bool = false
    var result: CustomModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            let _ = NSLog("Within VStack of ShowResponseView")
            Text("")
        }.onAppear(perform: {
            self.showingModal.toggle()
        }).sheet(isPresented: $showingModal, content: {
            let messageViewDetails = getMessageViewDetails()

            let _ = NSLog("Within sheet of ShowResponseView")
            ShowMessageAlert(rawValue: messageViewDetails.actionType.rawValue)?.generalMessageView(messageText: messageViewDetails.messageText, showingModal: $showingModal)
        })
    }

    // func for getMessageViewDetails
}
```

Whenever response is received, code within .response of OtherCustomView gets executed which calls ShowResponseView. I see "Within VStack of ShowResponseView" debug statement getting printed on console, but I never see "Within sheet of ShowResponseView". I also added debug statement within .onAppear() and I see that being printed too. I just don't see the sheet being presented.

Am I doing anything wrong here? How do I present a sheet programmatically?

Note: Working on watch app and on watchOS 7.0 version. Xcode - 13.4.1

Comment: Would you show CustomViewModel? I think the problem is there. At least `ShowResponseView` as standalone works fine for me.

Comment: I noticed what @tail is talking about in his response below. showingModal.toggle() wasn't doing anything onAppear(). Passing down showingModal value from OtherCustomView worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I tested, your "self.showingModal.toggle()" never did anything.

However, if whenever you call the "ShowResponseView(isSuccess: isSuccess, result: result)", you make the sheet appears automatically by toggle() the "showingModal", why not just pass true value to the "showingModal" variable?

I did this:

```
 ShowResponseView(showingModal: true)
```

Then, the sheet appeared normally, and "Within sheet of ShowResponseView" was also printed.